# Javascript/JQuery to display the total of individual seat costs

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use JavaScript/JQuery to display the total cost of the selected seats to allow a user to see a total of the extra costs they need to pay for their seating choices.

Each seat has a different value I'm pulling from a JSON file. 
So if seat 1C costs 4.99, 2B costs 5.99, 8C costs 13.99 and 8F costs 13.99, I want to be able to display the costs summed up.

This is what I have in my javascript to attach the JSON prices to the rows.

```
    var seatPrices1aTo1f = JSON.stringify(d.pricing[0].price);
    var seatPrices2aTo6f = JSON.stringify(d.pricing[1].price);
    var seatPrices7aTo11f = JSON.stringify(d.pricing[2].price);
    var seatPrices12aTo13f = JSON.stringify(d.pricing[3].price);
    var seatPrices14aTo23f = JSON.stringify(d.pricing[4].price);

    // Categories (and remove "" quotes)
    var cat1aTo1f = JSON.stringify(d.pricing[0].cat).replace(/"|-/g, "");
    var cat2aTo6f = JSON.stringify(d.pricing[1].cat).replace(/"|-/g, "");
    var cat12aTo13f = JSON.stringify(d.pricing[3].cat).replace(/"|-/g, "");

    console.log(seatPrices2aTo6f);
    console.log(5-6);

    $('.row1').children('td').attr({'data-price':seatPrices1aTo1f,'data-category':cat1aTo1f});
    $('.row2,.row3,.row4,.row5,.row6').children('td').attr({'data-price':seatPrices2aTo6f,'data-category':cat2aTo6f});
    $('.row7,.row8,.row9,.row10,.row11').children('td').attr({'data-price':seatPrices7aTo11f,'data-category':'Standard'});
    $('.row12,.row13').children('td').attr({'data-price':seatPrices12aTo13f,'data-category':cat12aTo13f});
    $('.row14,.row15,.row16,.row17,.row18,.row19,.row20,.row21,.row22,.row23').children('td').attr({'data-price':seatPrices14aTo23f,'data-category':'Standard'});
```

Comment: What's with all these `JSON.stringify(...)` calls? O.o

Comment: There is probably a FAR easier way to achieve your goals.

Comment: He's converting objects to strings..

Comment: I'm really new to JSON it's how I am bring the information from the JSON file to the js file.

Comment: How does someone pick a seat? Where's the code for that which deduces the price for a chosen seat?

Comment: What Table library are you using? probably there's some method `setData`. You don't have to attach the data manually.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney heres a short jsfiddle, not sure if its of any use. https://jsfiddle.net/xgrorxnp/1/

Comment: @giannisf I'm not sure what you mean my table library.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path/to/file/prices.json",
    success: function (data) {
        prices = JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```

for parsing the prices, and then something like

```
var total = 0;
$('.n:contains(\'F\') .selected').each(function(index, item){
    total += prices[item.id];
});
```

for calculating total price

Comment: of course this is just example, the exact code depends of your prices.json formatting